# Pass a package name to a lanch file and retrieve path

Tags: roslaunch

[image: Rosanswers logo]

hello,
i'm trying to pass a package name to launch file in order to find the path with $(find package_name_arg).
This fails and i don't know how to fix it.
Does anyone knows?
Thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/271856/pass-a-package-name-to-a-lanch-file-and-retrieve-path/) by [muttidrhummer](https://answers.ros.org/users/32095/muttidrhummer/) on ROS Answers with karma: 71 on 2017-09-29

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

```
<arg name="package" />
    <include file="$(eval find(package) + '/launch/demo.launch' )" />
```

SOLVED LIKE THIS
thanks

---

Originally posted by [muttidrhummer](https://answers.ros.org/users/32095/muttidrhummer/) with karma: 71 on 2017-09-29

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1